# directed graph and no directed cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Show that it is possible for a directed graph with $n$ vertices and no directed cycles to have $n(n−1)/2$ edges .

I am approaching by saying $2$ vertices are required for $1$ edge, so total number of edges is ${n\choose 2}$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Ok so that's the most number of edges a directed (simple) graph can have. But your question is asking if you can have a directed graph with this many edges **and** no directed cycles.

Comment: Notice that this is a *directed* graph, so each edge is determined by a pair of vertices $(u,v)$ where $u\ne v$.  So there are $n(n-1)$ possible edges, not $\frac12n(n-1)$ as there would be in an undirected graph.  For example, if $V=\{v_1, v_2\}$, there are 2 possible edges, namely $v_1\to v_2$ and $v_2\to v_1$; if the graph were undirected, there would be only one possible edge $v_1 \leftrightarrow v_2$.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want cycles, look for a tree-like structure.

For instance, call the vertices $1,\ldots,n$ and form a directed edge $i\to j$ whenever $i<j$.